# Windows 7 start menu width

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to make the start menu more wide in Windows 7. Many of my programs names can't fully be displayed in the menu with the default width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a program to do that: [Start menu width](http://szerokosc-menustart.pl/en/).

> Start menu width is a tool which can
>   change the width of the Start menu in
>   Windows Vista and Windows 7.

It's in Polish but the GUI is very easy to use. You can check the video on the program's web site.

Comment: That link is now broken.

Comment: Link rot sometimes happens. You can go to [this](http://bitsnoop.com/startwidth-1-1-q18227532.html) page and use the _direct download_ link to get the exe.